# Wifi Blocks Certain address alone

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, wifi-configuration

I am not a Networking person and have no idea how to figure this.

I am trying to VPN into my office network(from home) to access tools. All the tools are hosted under address 10.0.0.*. I am able to connect to my VPN but I am not able to access any tools.

My wifi is blocking all the requests(I tried ping . it time-outs). This is happening only for this ip addresses tools.

My Wireless network is COMCAST and the router is Xfinity(Arris).

I tried to connect through my phone's hotspot and it works(ATT).

How do I fix it? What is the cause of this?

INFO: I researched a little and I found that COMCAST uses 10.0.* address for its communication and hence conflict appears. To set up a NAT or personal hosting table. I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your admin tool of your router using the default password
Username – admin
Password – password (case-sensitive)
or the password(if you have customized it to a new one). Then check on the MAC address filtering section, whether the specific MAC address of your system is added to the list. 
Also refer to this link to get more clarity about the access to your settings on the router
http://customer.comcast.com/help-and-support/internet/wireless-gateway-username-and-password/

You can also set the NAT table list for the devices on  your router from the same Admin tool. Once you set up the NAT details along with the device name and the ip address of that device, the host will be opened.

Comment: It doesn't work. I have a hosts file under my /etc directory which maps the IP to the address. It still doesn't work.